# get location of a telegram user using R's telegram.bot library on CRAN

Tags: r, telegram, telegram-bot, cran

I am coding a telegram bot using R and the `telegram.bot` library on CRAN.

Since my application is spatially enabled I should know the user position when the `\hello` request is fired by the user (that previously has enabled the location).

Since the library has no `getLocation(...)` I opened an issue on the developer's github, but I had no feedback. Is there a way to retrieve the location of the user using directly some Telegram API?